# How do I change the permissions of a user for 600+ folders in Outlook via PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, permissions, office365, exchange-server, office365api

I'm trying to give an assistant access to part of someone's O365 mailbox. She currently has foldervisible permissions on his inbox. And there is about 607 folders under the inbox that she needs access to without having anymore permissions to the inbox itself.

Below is the code I've tried to run. I've removed the domain name but otherwise the code is exact. I've run the code twice and gotten no errors and it runs for a quite a while. But once it's complete, there is no change in the permissions.

```
ForEach($f in (Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics -identity jjo | Where { $_.FolderPath.Contains("jjo:/Inbox/Case Files") -eq $True } ) ) {
     $fname = "jjo:" + $f.FolderPath.Replace("/","\");
     Add-MailboxFolderPermission $fname -User gka -AccessRights Owner 
}
```

Comment: .contains() is case sensitive for one thing

Comment: Add some error trapping might help - use `Try....Catch` and `-ErrorAction Stop`

Answer (score 0):

Try to narrow down what's working and not;

```
Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics -identity jjo -ErrorAction Stop | Where-Object { $_.FolderPath.Contains("jjo:/Inbox/Case Files") } | ForEach-Object {
     Try {
        $fname = "jjo:" + $_.FolderPath.Replace("/","\")
        Write-Host "Amending: $fname ..."
        Add-MailboxFolderPermission $fname -User gka -AccessRights Owner -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host "Done"
     }
     Catch {
        $_
     }
}
Write-Host "Complete"
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried it and it's timing out. So I tried narrowing how many folders it was doing and it's still timing out. Even with 4 folders.

Comment: Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics : The operation has timed out. The operation has timed out.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics -identity jjo -ErrorAction Stop | Wher ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ProtocolError: (:) [Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : One or more errors occurred.,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RestApiClient.GetExoMailboxFo
   lderStatistics

Answer (score 0):

On the client side, Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) can be used modify the ACL table on the folder level. If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option (any language), you can use [RDOFolder.ACL](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOACL.htm) collection to modify the permissions. Something along the lines (VBA, off the op of my head):

```
ROLE_PUBLISH_EDITOR = &H4FB
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set AddressEntry = Session.AddressBook.GAL.ResolveName("The Other User Name")
set Folder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
for each subFolder in Folder.Folders
  set ACE = subFolder.ACL.Add(AddressEntry)
  ACE.Rights = ROLE_PUBLISH_EDITOR
next
```